# different div positions in IE9 FF and chrome

Tags: html, css

I have already asked this question but I didn't get a specific answer. so I thought to ask a simplified version of the question

I am making a website and want to place the div at a specific height. I cannot set the margin-top in px terms as if the browser window re sizes, the div remains at that px. I have specified this in %. if the margin-top is in px, it is fine in all browsers but if it is in % then IE9 IE10 and FF behave crazy.

The code below is very simple with nothing difficult. I even tried reset css but didn't get it right. can anyone please spare few moments and help me in this.

and i am currently loading the page from the harddisk not from the internet.

Thanks

```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Train of Thought</title>
  <style type="text/css">

div.content {
  height:200px;
  visibility:visible;
  border-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: 23%;
  margin-right:25%;
  font-size:150%;
  margin-top: 40%;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">This div is supposed to be same in all the browsers. but thisis different in them. IE9 and FF display it in lower bottom of the page while chrome displays in the middle.
<br>This div is supposed to be same in all the browsers. but thisis different in them. IE9 and FF display it in lower bottom of the page while chrome displays in the middle.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it works as expected in IE9, IE10 and FF. Please define what you mean by 'behaving crazy'

Comment: in IE9, IE10 and FF the div appears much below the it appears on google chrome. and I want it at the position where goofgle chrome displays it.

Comment: Testing on Firefox, I notice that the value used for the `margin-top: 40%` parameter is 40% of the available width, and not 40% of the available height, as you might expect.

Comment: I have also checked it in chrome. There it appears at exact the same position than in other browsers.

Comment: in chrome, the position is changed because of viewport width and height and you are giving margin-top in percentage! chrome has larger viewport than FF and IE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by it 'behaves crazy', that the div doesn't adjust dynamically it's position when you change the browser size, the reason is the way you position it.

you have set position to fixed, that means you define the exact position by top, bottom, left, right and not with margins.

Comment: I got it. I should use top:40% rather than margin-top:40%

Comment: that was answer of @Gareth Cornish! :) and you have to accept that if it solved your problem!

Comment: I got the problem solved by @Sven Bieder answer "hat means you define the exact position by top, bottom, left, right and not with margins." and it was before Gareth's answer

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">This div is supposed to be same in all the browsers. but thisis different in them. IE9 and FF display it in lower bottom of the page while chrome displays in the middle.
<br>This div is supposed to be same in all the browsers. but thisis different in them. IE9 and FF display it in lower bottom of the page while chrome displays in the middle.
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:1020px;
height:760px;
}
.content {
position:absolute;
top: /* you set it */
left: /* you set it */
/* other props */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I noted, the `margin-top` directive seems to calculate it's percentage from the width of it's parent element. But not so for the `top` directive. So, simply change:

```
margin-top: 40%;
```

To:

```
top: 40%;
```

I tried this on Firefox, Chrome and IE8, and they all worked the same.